# Which method is better when I execute the stored procedure which take a long time in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

I have a stored procedure in my ASP.NET MVC project using Telerik DataAccess ORM, its role is to calculate  a result and insert or update into a label.

For example, when I pass a parameter "2014" and invoke the stored procedure, it calculates the result and changes the table called `2014_Table`. When I pass a parameter "2013" and invoke the stored procedure, it calculates the result and changes the table called `2013_Table`. If I pass a parameter "2013,2014", it will calculate and change the table respectively.

Now my question is, if I pass a parameter "2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014", it will calculate and change the tables respectively but takes a long time (about two minutes). How to optimize it and reduce the execution time?

What I think is to use parallel way, which loop ten times to invoke the stored procedure by passing single year string, but it need to connect the database ten times? And the sp function is CPU intensive, does the parallel way really work? How about asynchronously way?

Comment: Without *any* ideas what this *calculates result and changes the table* really means, without seeing *any* code - this is impossible to answer

Comment: In fact, I just want to ask if the long-running stored procedures which is CPU intensive, whether used in parallel  is to improve efficiency?

Comment: Well, SQL Server itself already contains fairly sophisticated means of parallelizing queries if there's a benefit in doing so. So I don't think doing it yourself will be any help. What might be useful is to investigate whether you could do the calculation for multiple years in a single operation and then just "split up" the results for the years - instead of doing calculation ten times, one after another....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend using an asynchronous way to solve this problem because it is CPU intensive.